# Убывающая последовательность в массиве

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти сколько убывающая последовательность есть в массиве.

> [6,4,5,3,2]-[6,4],[5,3,2]  - 2
>
> [] - 0
>
> [7,3] - 1
>
> [3,4,5,6] - 0

Не понимаю каким образом делать)))

```
function solution(x){
    let y = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i]>x[i+1]) {
            y.push(x[i]);
        }
        return y.length
    }
}
console.log(solution([6,4,5,3,2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function solution(x) {
  let status = 0;
  let count = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i - 1] > x[i]) {
      if (!status) {
        status = 1;
        count++;
      }
    } else {
      status = 0;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(solution([6, 4, 5, 3, 2]));
```

Переменная `status` показывает, находимся мы внутри убывающей последовательности (`1`) или нет (`0`). В месте

```
      if (!status) {
        status = 1;
```

мы входим в новую убывающую последовательность.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста,что делает status, !status, в чем его смысл?

Comment: @TyomArshakyan Переменная `status` показывает, находимся мы внутри убывающей последовательности (`1`) или нет (`0`).

Comment: понятно,спасибо)))